# MySql find matches between words using query in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have Java program that is connected to a mysql database. What I want to do is take user input and display a column that matches with the user input. The column contains a list of programming languages. I need help with the sql query needed to do this.  For example if the column in the first row contained the languages Javascript, C++, C# and the column in the second row contained Java and if I used the query

```
"SELECT * from Language WHERE Programming Languages LIKE'%"+input.getText()+"%'")
```

and the user were to search for Java then the table would display the column that has Java and Javascript because it has the word Java. And if there was a third row and that column had C , and if the user were to search C, then it would display the columns with C++ and C#.

I tried to use this regex instead

```
`"SELECT * from Language WHERE Programming Language REGEXP'[[<:]]"+input.getText()+"[[:>:]]'")`
```

which solved the Java and Javascript problem, but searching for C would display the columns with C# and C++. Also searching for C# would display nothing and searching for C++ would throw this error repetition operator operand invalid.
[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1iVI.png)

The table's column data:

```
Javascript HTML CSS PHP
C# Java
C
C++ C#
```

I tried to put a space before % in the first query which works with differentiating. My question now is how do i search for multiple words in a column, the above query works for two or three inputs in exact order. Searching javascript and html would show but javascript and css would not show because its not in order

Comment: Can you show some example data in the table columns/rows?

Comment: just added the image, dont have enough rep to embed, so its posted as a link

Comment: You may want to try something like splitting a column's value into multiple substrings and work with it. Try searching/google with _"mysql split string column"_  for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just guess, you store all developers to a table, and one of the columns stores the languages that this developer masters.

When someone input a language, you want to search all the developers who master this language?

If so, I would do this, in your language column, in your language column, add an extra white space to the end (use `_` as white space below)

```
Javascript_HTML_CSS_PHP_
C#_Java_
C++_C#_
C_
Python_Java_LUA_
```

Then in your Java code, you could use the following code to do this.

```
SELECT * from Language WHERE Programming_Languages LIKE'%"+input.getText()+"_%'")
```

And please pay attention that you should never concatenate sql string in your Java code. You can do it in this way:

```
statment = con.prepare("SELECT * from Language WHERE Programming_Languages LIKE ?")
statment.setString(1, "%" + input.getText() + "_%")
```

Comment: This solution is not really any better than the original one - instead of using spaces as separator, you now use an underscore. It is not much different from looking for `LIKE '%LANG %'` in his original query (which would work exactly the same as your approach if he inserts additional spaces at the end of every string). However your approach also introduces an additional issue in case any programming language that has an udnerscore in its name is invented any time ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. Yes, I think adding a white space to every string is the easiest way. I just use `_` to represent the white space.

Comment: It might be the quickest approach. Doesn't make it the easiest. It's easy to, for example, forget to add a space when editing data, or in a string inside the applicaiton logic. ALso not that full text search in databases is a very slow operation compared to others, so you want to avoid it.

Comment: It would still show Javascript , if i to were search for Java

Comment: @JohannesH, I agree, it's the quickest way, not the best or easiest :)

Comment: Do you ad a white space in your query statement?  `SELECT * from Language WHERE Programming_Languages LIKE'%"+input.getText()+"_%'")` @SamuraiBale

Comment: Programming Languages is my column name for the table not Programming_Languages. I tried  SELECT * from Language WHERE Programming Languages LIKE'%"+input.getText()+"_%'") and it gave me javascript when searching for java. Im using a prepared statement if it matters.

Comment: @SamuraiBale It's not necessary, can you get the right result using other mysql client, like mysql console with the the sql `SELECT * from Language WHERE \`Programming Languages\` LIKE '%Java_%')`

Comment: I've tried on phpmyadmin, I get Java and Javascript when executing the query

Comment: @SamuraiBale It's interesting enough, if you truely add a white space to the query conditions it should't return the javascript result except that this developer masters both. And I'm sorry that I could not help you any more.

Comment: do you mind checking it out, it might be a problem on my end

Comment: ok i tried with space instead of _ and it works, however another problem arises when i want to check more than one skill that's in different order. For example, in the above if i search of javascript and css , my search is blank , but when i do javascript and html, my results show up

Comment: Both issues can be avoided using the solution I pointed out. Within the joined tables, you can also search for any combination of languages.

Comment: I agree with @JohannesH. if you still want to use this solution, you should use `and` statement. You will first break the user input into 2 works and use ·`SELECT * from Language WHERE \`Programming Languages\` LIKE '%Javascript %' and \`Programming Languages\` LIKE '%CSS %'`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that your database model is not correctly [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). While possible, it is not recommended to store multiple values in one column of a database. Instead, as a first step, use a seperate database to store the proghramming languages, and use unique indexes to map the values to people:

```
people

id    | name | other stuff
86511 | Bob  | ...         
86513 | TBA  | ...
```

.

```
languages

language | user_id
C#       | 86511
Java     | 86511
C++      | 86513
C#       | 86513
```

Now you can just search the table LANGUAGES for the corresponding language and map it o the users using a JOIN-clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM languages
  INNER JOIN people ON languages.user_id = people.id
WHERE languages.language = 'C#';
```

However, there is still room for optimizations: you now have multiple entries for each programming language in the languages table. This takes longer to search and has a potential to result in inconsistent databases if you accidentally have a typo in only one of the entries for the same language, for example.
To avoid all this, we can introduce a third table that only holds one entry for each langauge, and restructure the second table to be only a mapping:

```
 people

id    | name | other stuff
86511 | Bob  | ...         
86513 | TBA  | ...
```

.

```
lang_mapping

lang_id | user_id
1       | 86511
2       | 86511
3       | 86513
1       | 86513
```

.

```
languages

id | language
1  | C#
2  | Java
3  | C++
```

You can still query the tables and connect languages to usery by introducing another join to the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM languages
  INNER JOIN lang_mapping ON lang_mapping.lang_id = language.id
  INNER JOIN people ON lang_mapping.user_id = people.id
WHERE languages.language = 'C#'
```

NOw you have only one entry per language, you can easily search for each language and get all mapped users, and you can add individual new languages or mappings withgout modifying the users table at all.

This is the normalized form of your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the query. This is derived from this [post](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql).

This requires a *temporary* table with number of rows populated by numbers up to the maximum number of tokens (language strings separated by space, e.g., the string "Javascript HTML CSS PHP" has 4 tokens).

Create a temp table with numbers:

```
create temporary table temp_numbers as
    select 1 as num
    union all select 2 as num
    union all select 3 as num
    union all select 4 as num
    union all select 5 as num
;
```

Table with a column of programming language strings:

```
create table test_langs (
    col1 varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    col2 varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Insert some test data:

```
insert into test_langs values ('ID-1', 'Javascript HTML CSS PHP');
insert into test_langs values ('ID-2', 'C# Java');
insert into test_langs values ('ID-3', 'C');
insert into test_langs values ('ID-4', 'C# C++');
insert into test_langs values ('ID-5', 'Python Java LUA');
```

The query:

This select gets the exact match to the input string "C";

```
select col1, token from (
    select col1, substring_index(
        substring_index(col2, ' ', num), 
        ' ', 
        -1
    ) as token
from test_langs
join temp_numbers
    on char_length(col2) - char_length(replace(col2, ' ', '')) >= num - 1
) as individual_progamming_languages
where token='C';
```

The result:

```
+------+-------+
| col1 | token |
+------+-------+
| ID-3 | C     |
+------+-------+
```